# addEventListener

Tags: javascript

есть работающий обработчик формы

```
window.onload = function() {

d.getElementById('contact_sent').onclick = function(){
var error_msg = "field is required";
var error_d = "";       
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('text_area');
var errors = document.getElementsByClassName('error');     
var hasError = false;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if (elements[i].value == '' ){     
        hasError = true;       
        elements[i].style.border = "2px solid orange";
        errors[i].innerHTML = error_msg;                       
    } else if (elements[i].value != '') {                 
        elements[i].style.border = "";
        errors[i].innerHTML = error_d;
    }
} 
return !hasError; } }
```

как можно преобразовать код используя addEventListener по событию submit 
пробовал так, но даже имея ошибки, форма тут же отправляется

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');function error(){
var error_msg = "field is required";
var error_d = "";       
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('text_area');
var errors = document.getElementsByClassName('error');     
var hasError = false;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if (elements[i].value == '' ){     
        hasError = true;       
        elements[i].style.border = "2px solid orange";
        errors[i].innerHTML = error_msg;                       
    } else if (elements[i].value != '') {                 
        elements[i].style.border = "";
        errors[i].innerHTML = error_d;
    }
    } 
return !hasError;}; form.addEventListener('submit',error,false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в функцию error добавить параметр event и остановить отправку формы если есть ошибки.

```
function error(e) {
   ...

   if (hasError) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Comment: А на что вообще влияет возвращаемое из event listener-а значение?

Comment: Скорее всего ни на что.

Comment: добавление параметра ситуацию не исправило

Comment: ошибки устанавливаются флагом hasError = true, в цикле проверки, в случае их возникновения

Comment: вы ваш `return !hasError` убрали?

Comment: да , теперь работает. Но если честно то непонято зачем сдесь нужен дополнительный параметр. Я так понимаю тут всё дело в  e.preventDefault();

Comment: Да, именно в нем. return это моя привычка, извиняюсь.

Comment: про метод прочитал, вроде ясно стало. В любом случае спасибо Вам за ответ